# Python - New beginner question, invalid syntax from a example file

Tags: python, syntax

I am trying to learn myself python, but I am already failing at the basics.

I am going through a set of examples from a book, and the very first example was this:

```
import sys

Zero = ['  ***  ',' *   * ','*     *','*     *','*     *',' *   * ','  ***  ']
One = ['   *   ','  **   ','   *   ','   *   ','   *   ','   *   ','  ***  ']
Two = ['  ***  ',' *   * ',' *  *  ','   *   ','  *    ',' *     ',' ***** ']
Three = [' ***** ','     * ','   **  ','     * ','     * ',' *  *  ','  **   ']
Four = ['    *  ','   *   ','  *    ',' *     ',' ******','    *  ','    *  ']
Five = [' ***** ',' *     ',' ****  ','     * ','     * ',' *   * ','  ***  ']
Six = ['  *    ',' *     ',' *     ',' ****  ',' *   * ',' *   * ',' ****  ']
Seven = [' ***** ','     * ','    *  ','   *   ','  *    ',' *     ',' *     ']
Eight = ['  ***  ',' *   * ',' *   * ','  ***  ',' *   * ',' *   * ','  ***  ']
Nine = ['  **** ',' *   * ',' *   * ','  **** ','     * ','     * ','     * '] 

Digits = [Zero, One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine]

try:
    digits = sys.argv[1]
    row = 0
    while row < 7:
        line = ''
        column = 0
        while column < len(digits):
            number = int(digits[column])
            digit = Digits[number]
            line += digit[row] + ' '
            column += 1
        print(line)
        row += 1
except IndexError:
    print('usage: bigdigits.py <number>')
except ValueError as err:
    print(err, 'in', digits)
```

When I ran bigdigits.py 1351355, I got an error, saying SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax. I thought it had something to do with the wrong path or something, I am using C:\py3eg as the path for my programs. When I copied it to the C:\Python32 path, same thing happened. I even downloaded the code from the books website, and still got the error, so the code is apparantly fine.

The book is for Python 3 programming, and that I have Python version 3.2.1 installed.

If anyone could point out the reason for me getting this error, I would be very grateful!

Comment: Please provide more information: in particular, the *full* error message, including line and position where it's complaining. (Because what you've put there is valid.)

Comment: Maybe you've installed Python2.* in parallel, and accidentally use that for executing the script? Python2.* would complain about the `ValueError as err` part. What happens if you type `python` on the command line, which version does it display?

Comment: Your code is running fine - just checked . Check again about whether you are using python 2.*

Comment: Works for me with Python 2.6.1 as well.

Comment: @Kjell Evenson: Side note: I'm not sure what book you're using, but this code is arguably not a model of good Python programming.  It just looks too much like C code.  A more conventional Python version of this program would be clearer and probably shorter.  I would recommend that you check out some of the resources listed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904212/where-can-i-find-python-tutorials-aimed-at-people-who-are-already-programmers/904611#904611, for instance.

Comment: @EOL: perhaps you were thinking of something more like `print '\n'.join(' '.join(Digits[int(digits[column])][row] for column in range(len(digits))) for row in range(7))`?

Comment: @Paul: Something like this (maybe with a loop instead of the join), plus many other "details" (like defining `digits` directly as a list of lists), removing any use of indices and string concatenation, and following PEP 8 better…

Answer (score 4):

Your code is valid Python code in 2.6+ and 3+. However, it yields the following error message under Python 2.5:

```
File "syntax-error.py", line 31
  except ValueError as err:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

That is because Python 2.5 does not know the `as` keyword. In 2.5, you'd use a comma instead:

```
  except ValueError, err:
```

Note that this will break Python 3.x compatibility.

Instead of applying these patches to make your code run with the age-old 2.5, you should **switch to a newer Python** release.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I've checked again, and I am fairly certain that I have v.3.2.1, it says so when I go in IDLE, and press "About". About the error message Chris, it just says SyntaxError: invalid syntax in the IDLE Python shell, and the numbers I enter after bigdigits.py is marked red.

Answer (score 0):

For better readability, try this syntax for defining Zero thru Nine (although these would be better named as "zero" through "nine", or even "_0" thru "_9" - save the capitalized names for classes, not variables):

```
Zero = """\
  ***  
 *   * 
*     *
*     *
*     *
 *   * 
  ***  """.splitlines()
```

**EDIT**: Here's some split/zip/* magic to define your digits:

```
digitparts = """\
  ***  |   *   |  ***  | ***** |    *  | ***** |  *    | ***** |  ***  |  **** 
 *   * |  **   | *   * |     * |   *   | *     | *     |     * | *   * | *   * 
*     *|   *   | *  *  |   **  |  *    | ****  | *     |    *  | *   * | *   * 
*     *|   *   |   *   |     * | *     |     * | ****  |   *   |  ***  |  **** 
*     *|   *   |  *    |     * | ******|     * | *   * |  *    | *   * |     * 
 *   * |   *   | *     | *  *  |    *  | *   * | *   * | *     | *   * |     * 
  ***  |  ***  | ***** |  **   |    *  |  ***  | ****  | *     |  ***  |     * """.splitlines()

Digits = zip(*(s.split('|') for s in digitparts))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Eclipse + Pydev，python v.3.2.3, your code is worked well in both Eclipse and IDLE.The point is the word "as" in the sentence "except ValueError as err:" not a key word in your IDE,so I think you should switch your python a higher version.